# Losing left menu when going back PKRevealController

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I'm implementing `PKRevealController` in an existing project. This project uses Storyboards, but user is able to play Cocos2D 2.0 game within the app.

My problem is that when user goes out of Cocos2D, I use a notification (notification center) on my navigation controller (that controls the Cocos2D game) to segue to my main view, but when it does the segue the `PKRevealController` doesn't work anymore.

I implement the `PKReveal` on my `AppDelegate`, so I suppose I should (somehow) implement it somewhere i can re-implement it when i exit a Cocos2d game.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone has the same problem, there's how I solved this problem:

- Created a new `UIViewController` in Storyboard, and embed it in a `NavigationCotroller`
- Created my InitialViewController for this new ViewController and implemented both `<PKRevealing, UIApplicationDelegate>`.
- Created thise properties in it:

  ```
  @property (nonatomic, strong) PKRevealController *revealController;
  @property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *myNavController;
  @property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
  ```
- On `viewDidLoad` did `self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];` (like on my `AppDelegate`)
- Finally on `viewDidAppear` method:

  `FrontViewController *frontViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FrontViewController"];`

  `PortraitAppNavigationController *frontNavigationController = [[PortraitAppNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:frontViewController];`

  `LeftMenuViewController *leftViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LeftMenu"];`

  `// Step 2: Instantiate.
  self.revealController = [PKRevealController revealControllerWithFrontViewController:frontNavigationController leftViewController:leftViewController];
  // Step 3: Configure.
  self.revealController.delegate = self;
  self.revealController.animationDuration = 0.25;`

  `// Step 4: Apply.
  self.window.rootViewController = self.revealController;`

  `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];`